# How do you write a variable value to an mvc cshtml page in aspnetcore2

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Its an .aspnet core2 site.
I've been doing 'trial and error' with different methods.

None of these work except the date line so I know razor is working.
I simply want to  set the value of Userid in code  and have it appear as a value of a hidden element. Didn't think it would get so  complicated.

> Index.cshtml

```
@model iBasisMobileV14.Models.AccountViewModels.CheckoutViewModel
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using iBasisMobileV14.Models.AccountViewModels

.......
@DateTime.Now.Year //Works OK

@Model.UserID // Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
@Html.Raw(UserID);
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserID , new { @id = "M_UserID" })
<input asp-for="UserID" id="M_UserID"   />
```

> CheckoutViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace iBasisMobileV14.Models.AccountViewModels
{
    public class CheckoutViewModel
    {
        //[Display(Name = "UserID")]
        private string _UserID;

        public string UserID
        {
            get {
                _UserID = "blabla";
                return _UserID; }
            set { _UserID = value; }
        }


    }
}
```

> CheckoutController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using NLog;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using iBasisMobileV14;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using iBasisMobileV14.Models;
using iBasisMobileV14.Data.EntityModel;
using iBasisMobileV14.Classes;

namespace iBasisMobileV14.Controllers
{

    public class CheckoutController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private AppSettings _appSettings { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; private set; }

        public CheckoutController(
           IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
              IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            //Session needs something set or it changes every page load

            UserID = "ccccccccc";


        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            Guid userId = new Guid(_userManager.GetUserId(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User));
            ViewData["UserID"] = "sdfdsfdfsdfdsfd"; //  userId;
            // Logger.Info("Front");
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You not passing a model to the view in the GET method so the model is `null` (you cannot access properties of an object which is `null`. Just pass an instance of your `CheckoutViewModel` model (with the `UserID` set) using `return View(yourModel);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your view is strongly typed to an instance of `CheckoutViewModel` and in your view you are accessing the UserID property.But in your GET action, you are not passing anything to the view. So essentially `Model` in your view is null. You should not be accessing a property/call a method on `NULL`, but that is what you are trying to do by executing this line `@Model.UserID` in your view.

So the solution is, create an object of your view model class and pass that object to the view.

```
var vm=new CheckoutViewModel();
Guid userId = Guid.NewGuid();  // to do : Replace with your code to get a valid Guid
vm.UserID = userId.ToString();
return View(v);
```

And in the view you can use input tag helper.

```
@model CheckoutViewModel
<input asp-for="UserID" type="hidden" />
```

But this will generate a hidden input which has value `blabla` because that is what  your `get` part of the property is returning! Unless you are not doing some logic in generating the property value, no need to use the private property. You can simply use a public property

```
public class CheckoutViewModel
{
  public string UserID { set;get;}
}
```